# AWS Beanstalk application cant deploy because Python version within awscli-bundle deployer too old

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

My AWS Elastic Beanstalk tomcat Java application that has been running quite happily for the last six months crashed yesterday, and when I try to redeploy using clone it fails

> Instance: i-0872ed7568a9820f5] Command failed on instance. Return
> code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...detected: Python 2.7 To continue using
> this installer you must use Python 3.6 or later. For more information
> see the following blog post:
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-python-2-7-in-aws-sdk-for-python-and-aws-cli-v1/.
> command 01_install_cli in .ebextensions/copyindexes.config failed. For
> more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

I check the **eb_activity.log** and it seems the problem is with the version of awscli-bundle used, but I dont understand where I define this.

```
Archive:  awscli-bundle.zip
  inflating: awscli-bundle/install
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/jmespath-0.10.0.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/pyasn1-0.4.8.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/docutils-0.15.2.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/s3transfer-0.5.0.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/virtualenv-16.7.8.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/awscli-1.20.1.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/six-1.16.0.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/rsa-4.7.2.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/colorama-0.4.3.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/urllib3-1.26.6.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/botocore-1.21.1.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/python-dateutil-2.8.2.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/setup/setuptools_scm-3.3.3.tar.gz
  inflating: awscli-bundle/packages/setup/wheel-0.33.6.tar.gz
  Unsupported Python version detected: Python 2.7
  To continue using this installer you must use Python 3.6 or later.
  For more information see the following blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-python-2-7-in-aws-sdk-for-python-and-aws-cli-v1/
  
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I have looked within the .ebextensions folder of my .war file and I cannot see a version number defined

So I tried creating a new environment using a newer platform so thinking the amazon cli tool is installed as part of the platform  instead of using *Tomcat 7 with Java 7* I tried *Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.2.2*

Now I get a different error in cfn-init.log of

```
2021-07-17 07:26:02,021 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-07-17 07:26:02,028 [INFO] Running configSets: _OnInstanceBoot
2021-07-17 07:26:02,031 [INFO] Running configSet _OnInstanceBoot
2021-07-17 07:26:02,033 [INFO] Running config AWSEBBaseConfig
2021-07-17 07:26:02,228 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2021-07-17 07:26:02,234 [INFO] Running config AWSEBCfnHupEndpointOverride
2021-07-17 07:26:02,237 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2021-07-17 07:26:02,238 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2021-07-17 07:26:02,238 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2021-07-17 07:26:37,586 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-07-17 07:26:37,592 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-07-17 07:26:37,596 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-07-17 07:26:37,599 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_jthinkws
2021-07-17 07:26:39,257 [ERROR] Command 01_install_cli (wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip; unzip awscli-bundle.zip;  ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws) failed
2021-07-17 07:26:39,257 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_jthinkws: Command 01_install_cli failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_install_cli failed
2021-07-17 07:26:39,260 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-07-17 07:26:39,260 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_install_cli failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_install_cli failed
```

I dont understand how I am meant to get round this because **01_install_cli** is not a script that I have written, it is not part of war file it is an internal script used by Amazon !

Answer (score 0):

There is **no automated migration** from EB platform based on `Amazon Linux 1` to  `Amazon Linux 2`. You have to do it **manually** in new EB platform, as explain in AWS docs:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: Thx, ok but I wasnt trying to migrate from Linux 1 to Linux 2 Do I have to do this, i.e is my existing version impossible to redeploy as before. Secondly where do you configure Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2, or are yo saying that al the Amazon pklatform instances are now Linux 2

Comment: @PaulTaylor What do you mean that you didn't try. You wrote that you did: "So I tried creating a new environment using a newer platform so thinking the amazon cli tool is installed as part of the platform instead of using Tomcat 7 with Java 7 I tried Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.2.2". The [only supported version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.javase) are based on Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Ok im finding al a bit confusing but I mean two things. Firstly why is not possible to just clone my existing env that worked until yesterday, or alternatively clone and update platform version from 2.7.6 to 3.4.8. As neither of these options did work I tried using a different platform branch (Tomcat 8.5 Coretto) instead and that failed with the error above, and the failure seems to occur before even got as far as deploying my code so I dont how understand how I can fix that ?

Comment: hi @Marcin i have found sourcve of issue but not sure how to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68418789/how-do-i-replace-this-aws-cli-command-that-is-no-longer-working-when-i-deploy-el any help appreciated as this is my production application down.