# How do I replace this AWS CLI command that is no longer working when I deploy Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have to redeploy my elastic beanstalk application today and it is no longer working because of some issue with withdrawal of support for Python 2

> Instance: i-0872ed7568a9820f5] Command failed on instance. Return
> code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...detected: Python 2.7 To continue using
> this installer you must use Python 3.6 or later. For more information
> see the following blog post:
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-python-2-7-in-aws-sdk-for-python-and-aws-cli-v1/.
> command 01_install_cli in .ebextensions/copyindexes.config failed. For
> more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

I dont directly use Python 2, but have tracked down the issue to
**copyindexes.config** file i have in my **.ebextensions** folder and contains the following line

```
    01_install_cli:
            command: wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip; unzip awscli-bundle.zip;  ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
    
    02_get_index:
         command:
           aws s3 cp --region eu-west-1 s3://jthink/release_index_21.tar.gz /home/ec2-user/release_index.tar.gz;
           aws s3 cp --region eu-west-1 s3://jthink/artist_index_21.tar.gz /home/ec2-user/artist_index.tar.gz;
           cd /usr/share/tomcat7;
           tar -xvf /home/ec2-user/release_index.tar.gz;
           tar -xvf /home/ec2-user/artist_index.tar.gz;
           rm /home/ec2-user/release_index.tar.gz;
           rm /home/ec2-user/artist_index.tar.gz;
```

How should I change this to to resolve the issue

**Update**

Ok so I modified script to

```
   01_install_cli:
    command: wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle-1.18.200.zip; unzip awscli-bundle-1.18.200.zip;  ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
```

That bit seemed to work but then in eb_activity.log I now get

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 884, in emit
      stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)
  Logged from file util.py, line 476
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 884, in emit
      stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
  Logged from file util.py, line 476
```

So looks like I picked a bad version , what should I have picked ?

**I tried with 1.19.0 and same error so maybe the issue is the aws-cli version but what is it**

I've only modified the download and install cli line, when I had the install line wrong it gave error about that so I must have that right but I have no idea where this new error is coming from.

Comment: These lines all seem ok. The problem is that the virtual machine you're running them on has Python 2 installed, while it should have Python 3. Where does that come from?

Comment: Update the platform version of your EB environment to Python 3.6 and you’ll be good to go.

Comment: The virtual machine is Tomcat 7 and Java 7 machine provided by amazon as the platform. I did try launching using a different platform but that failed with different errors so I think what I want to do is instead amend this script so that it uses version of aws-cli that doesn't require Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know Python 2 is deprecated. In order to use the AWS CLI version 1 with an older version of Python, you need to install an earlier version of the AWS CLI version 1.

> Python 2.7 was deprecated by the Python Software Foundation on January 1, 2020. Going forward, customers using the AWS CLI version 1 should transition to using Python 3, with a minimum of Python 3.6. **Python 2.7 support is deprecated for new versions of the AWS CLI version 1 starting 7/15/2021.**

Check the official [AWS documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html)

Best,
Stefan

Comment: Yes thats the longterm plan, but switching to a platform that support Python 3 has knock on effects that will cause other things to break (e.g wil be using later versions of Java and Tomcat) not totally compatible with code. This is production system so I just want to get it up and running with minimal changes.

Comment: In order to use the AWS CLI version 1 with an older version of Python, you need to install an earlier version of the AWS CLI version 1.

Comment: @Taylor For example try version 1.19.0

Comment: is that the right version, is there a;list because I had 1.18.200 and that didnt work

Comment: It doesnt matter what version I use seems to give this unicode error regardless, i dot know why.

Comment: Found similar error here https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell/issues/4674 but no idea how it relates to my problem.

Comment: Can you make sure that the binary you are executing has the correct version? For example, if you didn't rebuild the your EB environment it might be the old binary...